How can I use vanilla javascript to set up a mobile nav to function where clicking the parent nav item will search for a child ul item and add class?
I am trying to set up a mobile nav so that clicking a "parent" nav item will search for the sub-menu ul contained within and toggle an "active" class to make it appear. Bonus points to add a function where it closes any other "active" sub-menus when opening a new one
The default menu will have the sub-menus hidden unless the "active" class is added to it, but I need a way to check if the parent nav item is clicked before adding that to the corresponding sub-menu item within.
I tried the JS below (as well as some other methods) but what I'm missing is how to set up a loop where it checks if the parent menu item is clicked and if so toggle the active class on the child ul (sub-menu) within. Any help appreciated.


document.querySelectorAll('#menu-mobile .main-wrap ul > li').forEach((it) => {
  it.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
     ev.preventDefault();
     it.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
#menu-mobile {
position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    width: 200px;
    right: 0;
    }

#menu-mobile .main-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: calc(10vh);
    position: relative;
    }

#menu-mobile .main-wrap ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    #menu-mobile .main-wrap ul > li ul {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #333333;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    
   #menu-mobile .main-wrap ul > li ul.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1; 
    }
    
    
<div id="menu-mobile">
  <div class="main-wrap">
    <ul id="menu-mobile-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-12800">
        <a href="www.google.com">Menu Item 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-1263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1263">
              <a href="www.google.com">Sub Menu Item 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
        <li id="menu-item-12800">
        <a href="www.google.com">Menu Item 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-1264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1264">
              <a href="www.google.com">Sub Menu Item 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>




I'm not sure I understand. Clicking the parent menu already opens the sub menu. Are you just asking for it to close open sub menus when another is selected?

Clicking the parent menu doesnt open the sub menu at least on my wordpress site. I had a blank link and i've tried either making the click event the blank  tag or the  of the nav item. Neither adds the active class to the submenu ul. I think something in my each loop isn't set up properly maybe?
The problem I was trying to solve was that clicking a drop down arrow would open the li link so I want to remove the link and make it so clicking the li will open the sub-menu instead

Ah, add document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { /*yourcodehere*/ }); around your javascript. It's most likely running before the document has printed.

I found some errors in the code and fixed it.
First, I added > before ul here since we don't need it for sub menu ul.
document.querySelectorAll('#menu-mobile .main-wrap ul > li').forEach...

document.querySelectorAll('#menu-mobile .main-wrap > ul > li').forEach...

Second, since there will be a sub menu, you should not put URL in your main menu:
<a href="www.google.com">Menu Item 1</a>

<a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>

And you don't need it anymore (unless you need it for your sub menu):
ev.preventDefault();

So for your JS, it should be like this:
document.querySelectorAll('#menu-mobile .main-wrap > ul > li').forEach(it => {
it.onclick = function(ev) {
    document.querySelectorAll('#menu-mobile .sub-menu.active').forEach(subMenu => {
        if (it.querySelector('.sub-menu') != subMenu ) subMenu.classList.remove('active');
    });
    it.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('active');
}

});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #menu-mobile {
position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    width: 200px;
    right: 0;
    }

#menu-mobile .main-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: calc(10vh);
    position: relative;
    }

#menu-mobile .main-wrap ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    #menu-mobile .main-wrap ul > li ul {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #333333;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    
   #menu-mobile .main-wrap ul > li ul.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1; 
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu-mobile">
        <div class="main-wrap">
          <ul id="menu-mobile-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-12800">
              <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
               <li id="menu-item-1263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1263">
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
             </li>
              <li id="menu-item-12800">
              <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1264">
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <script>

document.querySelectorAll('#menu-mobile .main-wrap > ul > li').forEach(it => {
    it.onclick = function(ev) {
        document.querySelectorAll('#menu-mobile .sub-menu.active').forEach(subMenu => {
            if (it.querySelector('.sub-menu') != subMenu ) subMenu.classList.remove('active');
        });
        it.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('active');
    }
});

      </script>
</body>
</html>




Thank you! this did it. It actually didn't work until I changed the parent nav item class but that was something specific to my Wordpress site and not the example I provided
